# What are the requirements to make a lambda constexpr?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, constexpr, c++20

Several times, in code review, I'm told to add `contexpr` to some named lambda closure declaration, i.e. I'm told to change this

`auto lam = [capture list](args){body}`

to this:

`constexpr auto lam = [capture list](args){body}`

Therefore, I'd like to understand what the conditions are that allow a lambda closure to be declared as `constexpr`, so I can make this change autonomously.

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) I read that

> A constexpr variable must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - its type must be a LiteralType.
> - it must be immediately initialized
> - the full-expression of its initialization, including all implicit conversions, constructors calls, etc, must be a constant expression
> - *[a C++20-specific condtion]*

Where I see that the second condition is verified, but I'd like some help understanding the first and especially the third condition.

Concerning the first condition, at the [*LiteralType*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) page I understand that it is enough, for a variable to be a LiteralType, to be a *possibly cv-qualified class type that has a destructor* (how could it not have one?) and *is a closure type* (which is the case for the `lam` above), and *all non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types* (I'm not sure about this last part in relation to lambdas).

The bottom line is that I'd like to understand how I can understand, by inspection, if I can make a lambda `constexpr`.

Comment: The page doesn't say "has a destructor", it says either "has a trivial destructor" (for C++17) or "has a constexpr destructor" (C++20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that decides whether a lambda can be `constexpr` is the capture list. The body can be non-`constexpr` and a `constexpr` lambda can still have parameters like `std::string`, which are not literal types either.

> its type must be a LiteralType.

The *LiteralType* requirement for lambdas effectively means that all captured members have to be non-volatile literal types too. Defining a lambda is equivalent to defining an anonymous `struct` where the captured variables are members.

```cpp
constexpr int x = 0;
constexpr auto lam = [x](){};

// equivalent to:
struct Lam {
    int x;
    void operator()() {}
};
constexpr Lam lam2{x};
```

When we think of lambdas as such `struct`s with call operators, it also becomes obvious what all these requirements mean. We can't capture a non-literal type, because that would require storing a non-literal type in this `struct`. And that can't happen in a `constexpr` context.

> the full-expression of its initialization, including all implicit conversions, constructors calls, etc, must be a constant expression

Once again, this basically states that capturing variables has to happen in a `constexpr` way. All captured variables must be `constexpr`, otherwise the initialization won't be. In fact, `constexpr` variables are all implicitly captured. **So what this really means is that a lambda can be made `constexpr` exactly when it doesn't have a capture list, or that capture list could be omitted.**

Comment: ... and the lambda isn't `mutable` (because then that would just be silly).